# Performing surface albedo calculation using Landsat 7 and Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to run this code with Google Earth Engine but I get an error on a Land sat 7 dataset.

> expression is not a function

my code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(ROI);
var albedo = dataset.expression(
  "((0.356*blue)+(0.130*red)+(0.373*nir)+(0.085*swir)+(0.072*swir2)- 0.018)/ 1.016",
  {
    red: dataset.select('B3'),
    blue:  dataset.select('B1'),
    nir:  dataset.select('B4'),
    swir:  dataset.select('B5'),
    swir2:  dataset.select('B7')
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

`expression` appears to only work on images. So, you can instead use `.map()` to apply your expression as a function to the whole image collection. The code below will add albedo as an additional band to each image in the collection `dataset` (also note that I added a county from Maine as a stand-in ROI).

```
var maineCounties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Waldo'));
print(maineCounties);
var ROI = maineCounties;

var albedo = function(image){
  var alb = image.expression(
  "((0.356*blue)+(0.130*red)+(0.373*nir)+(0.085*swir)+(0.072*swir2)- 0.018)/ 1.016",
  {
    'red': image.select('B3'),
    'blue':  image.select('B1'),
    'nir':  image.select('B4'),
    'swir':  image.select('B5'),
    'swir2':  image.select('B7')
  });
  return(image.addBands(alb.rename("albedo")));
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(ROI)
                  .map(albedo);

print("dataset",dataset);

var myAlbedo = dataset.select("albedo"); // To isolate just the albedo band
print("myAlbedo",myAlbedo); // Look at it
```